# MacVim: get Vsplit width

Tags: scrollbar, vim

I wanted to modify the function created by Andreas Politz (discussion here: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_use/6bO-QKWj9_4/2cdqygSqcMgJ) to work with vsplits too. This function creates a horizontal scrollbar to indicate the current position in the file (I actually don't like MacVim default scrollbars). The size of the scrollbar depends on the width of the whole window and does not adapt to vsplit. As I use NERDTree plugin, every vsplit has a oversized scrollbar.

I've done some searches on StackOverflow and VIM wiki but I only found commands to resize the vsplit and none to get the actual size.

Do you have any clue on how to get the current vsplit width?

PS: My results so far:

- `:set columns` returns actual window size
- `:set winwidth` returns the minimum width of window
- `:set window` gives me a number that doesn't change when I switch between splits (`77` each time)

Comment: I'd like to see a screenshot of this script in usage.

Comment: @romainl: Screenshot [here](http://img195.imageshack.us/img195/4300/capturedcran20121010100.png). As you can see, the scrollbar fits now but except for the current window, the cursor is not synchronized with the current position. Hopefully, it doesn't bother me for now.

Comment: I'd say it's normal that the cursor position is not updated in non-current windows since it doesn't change. But their position appears to be wildly wrong: in the top window it should be on the 7th step and in the bottom left window it should be on the last step.

Comment: In fact, when I switch from window 1 to window 2, the window 1's cursor goes to the same place as 2's then it doesn't update when I move around in window 2. That makes the weird position in top window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
:echo winwidth(0)
```

returns the width of window `0`.

See `:help functions` for a comprehensive list of functions available in Vim. The documentation is the first place you should visit if you are looking for anything Vim-related.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I'm still struggling a bit with the integrated help so the `:help functions` will be very useful.